# Check HMAC-SHA1 without key in C#

Tags: c#, salt, hmacsha1

I am generating HMAC-SHA1 without key in C# and it returns every time different hash for same value, how can I match hashes,

My code is https://dotnetfiddle.net/3a3tiP

- is it possible or not to match these hashes?
- I think HMAC-SHA1 not possible without key Am I right?
- If above 'Yes' then why C# allow to generate without key and how is it doing?

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should *not* be converting the hash to a string using `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hmac)`. It's not a UTF-8-encoded string. Use base64 or hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because you are using parameterless constructor to build HMACSHA1 instance, and [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha1(v=vs.110).aspx)

> HMACSHA1() - Initializes a new instance of the HMACSHA1 class with a randomly generated key.

Just add some constant key and you'll get same hash every time. e.g.

```
var hmacSha = new HMACSHA1(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("yourConstantKey"));
```

And answering your questions:

1. Yes, use same key for 2 generations.
2. Yes.
3. It generates random key for you

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [`HMACSHA1`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1(v=vs.90).aspx):

> A Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC) can be used to determine whether a message sent over an insecure channel has been tampered with, provided that the sender and receiver share a secret key.

So yes, you need a key. If you don't specify a key, one will be generated for you, and you can fetch it with the [`Key` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmac.key(v=vs.90).aspx) afterwards (e.g. to store it). Or you can specify it in the constructor, or set the `Key` property, either because you've received it from the other party, or because you want to reuse a previously-generated key.

If you hash the same data using the same key, you should get the same hash as a result.

As noted in comments, you should *not* then convert the HMAC to a string using `Encoding.GetString`, because it's arbitrary binary data - it's *not* encoded text. The simplest approach is probably to use base64 instead:

```
string base64Hmac = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac);
```